# Rewrite rules in httpd.conf instead of .htaccess?

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

All of the tutorials I've seen (such as [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7)) for using Rewrite rules with Apache on Centos show how to enable .htaccess and then put the rules in there, which requires enabling `AllowOverRide All` in `httpd.conf` for the www directory being used.

From a security standpoint I would think it better to keep .htaccess disabled and put the rewrites into httpd.conf (or .../sites-enabled/example.net.conf). Indeed, this is the advice of the Apache manual, [When (not) to use .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when).

Is there a good reason using httpd.conf for rewrites isn't common practice?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a good reason using httpd.conf for rewrites isn't common
>   practice?

A large number of the consumers of the tutorials you've read are customers of shared webhosts, whom don't have access to modify the main apache configuration, but *do* typically have the ability to place rewrite rules in `.htaccess` files in their web document root.

You're right in saying that it's preferred to put configuration in the main config file if possible. This is for two reasons: first, there's a very slight performance gain, in that the webserver doesn't need to be constantly re-reading the `.htaccess` file, and second, security - your httpd.conf is typically much more well-protected from modifications than your `.htaccess` file(s).

Comment: And cargo cult administration too.

Comment: The example tutorial reference, from Digital Ocean, starts with editing the httpd.conf to add the allow override, so not a shared webhost situation. (Not to pick on Digital Ocean specifically. It's just that their tutorials consistently show at top of apache tutorial search results.)

Comment: Many of DO's users have outgrown shared webhost environments. DO is merely catering to their customer base, for which I cannot fault them. That doesn't change my answer. :)

Comment: To clarify, putting config directives in .htaccess isn't *wrong* per se. It's just not ideal if you have other options.

Comment: And third! Every kind of redirection and practically any kind of configuration becomes more complex in per-dir context. About 90% of the issues most people have, and I'm not exagerating would be gone if people defined more virtualhosts and redirections in that context instead of going for an all out solve every situation .htaccess.